# Grafana singlestat value color

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I need to change value color to black in singlestat pannel, and backgrund color by mertic.
How to change the color of the value separately from the background color?

Example:

Background color green - value color black
Background color red - value color black
In example i do it with F12, and set color manualy, but certainly its not permanent.

[Example panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8OfV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Those colors below are where you would do it, and make sure to save your graph to persist the changes.

You can think of the single stat as like an "alert", 
let's say that

- x < 10 is "ok"
- 10 < x < 25 is "ehhh"
- x > 50 is "very bad"

you would have your single-stat display those colors when it is also displaying those values. So

- green == "ok"
- orange == "ehhh"
- red == "very bad"

those values just above the colors you have are where you would set those value/color pairs. If you only want one color, only set one value.

To have the value color follow the status color, click `value`